# how to get the index of dynamically created element (list item)?

Tags: jquery

```
<ul class="siteName"></ul>
```

In the above un order list i am appending the `<li></li>` for some n(10) item.

on click on the the `<li>` how to get the index of get the index of the `li` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, it is clear that your `li` has child tags inside it, so the click event will generate it for them too. So you should write the code as,

```
$('.siteName').on('click', 'li', function(e){
        alert($(this).closest("li").index());

    });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/251/)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `element.index()` to get its index in relative to its siblings,

```
$('.siteName').on('click','.siteName > li',function(){
  console.log($(this).index()); //index of the clicked li, index starts from 0
});
```

If you don't want to exclude the nested li element's click then use,

```
$('.siteName').on('click','li',function(){
  console.log($(this).index()); //index of the clicked li, index starts from 0
});
```

Comment: The `.siteName` is not required in the `.on()` method

Comment: @andyb why.? i am delegating to it, since it is the static parent.

Comment: Since you are giving the parent as .siteName, it will bind the events only to its children. So there is no need to explicitly specify '.siteName > li'

Comment: @AnoopJoshi What if OP wants to exclude the nested li elements..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy then its ok.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul.siteName').on('click', 'li', function(e){
var index=$(this).index();
}
```

Comment: this wont work. Elements are dynamic. So this binding wont be reflect on newly created elements

Comment: every time i am getting alert of 1.... since i am appending the li dynamically how to get the index of this ?

Comment: @Krish you should use $('.siteName').on('click','li',function(){

Comment: @Anoop  - still its not getting the every index element... on click every list item it getting alert of 1 :(

Comment: @Krish, Please provide your dynmaic li append string.

Comment: @RGS - even your solution also not working... every time its getting index 1 as in my alert....

Comment: @Krish, show your whole code, how you are appending it, or the rendered html

Comment: @Krish, Please check fiddle demo provided by anoop joshi.

Comment: @Manwal - $('ul.listStyle01 li').on('click', 'a', function () {}); this is my click function and the ul and the list a is binding through knockoutjs:<ul data-bind="foreach: mySiteSectionViewModel.CommonList" class="listStyle01">
                        <li>
                            <span class="chkboxStyle01 chkboxStyle01Normal columnLeft">&nbsp;</span>
                            <a data-bind="html:$data,  click: mySiteSectionViewModel.showFocusAreaList" class="columnLeft siteName"></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul> how to get the index of this list anchor item ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code:

```
$('.siteName').on('click', 'li', function(e){
        var index=$(this).index();
        alert(index);
    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fp7Qn/)

### Update

Click event should be on `li` not `a`. see changes in code and compare with yours.

**Updated Code:**

```
$('ul.listStyle01').on('click', 'li', function () {
        var index = $(this).index(); alert(index); 
    });
```

[<kbd>Another Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/AC8uj/1/)

Comment: Thanks for all your solutions... suppose if the list item is generated through knockoutJS... will it work ?

Comment: Ya sure @Krish it will.

Comment: Manwal: <ul data-bind="foreach: mySiteSectionViewModel.CommonList" class="listStyle01"><li><span class="chkboxStyle01 chkboxStyle01Normal columnLeft">&nbsp;</span><a data-bind="html:$data,  click: mySiteSectionViewModel.showFocusAreaList" class="columnLeft siteName"></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>                                                                     and  my js is : $('ul.listStyle01 li').on('click', 'a', function () {
   var index = $(this).index();
   alert(index);
 }); this time i cant get the index count? cn u help ?

Comment: Your jquery code is not correct, I have made some changes check them.I have updated answer @Krish . Thanks

Comment: @Krish did you check the answer?